# Poser 3D Characters - > Then draw them in 2D

Tags: animation, grease-pencil, 2d

A 2d animators question:

I want to animate 2d characters in Blender, since I realized how powerful it can be for 2d animation.

I want to pose a 3D character, then redraw the pose with the grease pencil, but i got some issues:

- After posing the characters and placing the camera I want to draw on top of the characters. the the pencil lines appears anywhere at the viewport, not in the selected camera view

-and I want to regulate the opacity of the 3d characters, so I can see my inkings, even if they are behind the characters.

All in all I want the function presented here with Clipstudio: https://www.pinterest.de/pin/375065475209393062/

Comment: The lines do not appear "anywhere in the viewport". They appear precisely in a single plane, one that is defined by the placement of the 3D cursor and the view in which you are drawing. The opacity depends on the material chosen for the particular brush and grease pencil layer.

Comment: thank you susu. It helped! I also find this tutorial helpful for others who wants to do that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mGRt24fYYWU&list=LL&index=1&ab_channel=MarcoBucci

Comment: If you solved your issue, please write a complete answer in the answers section so that others that run into the same problem can learn from your experience.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

- place your camera
- pose your characters as you want
- apply any other material to the characters (I don't know if it affects previous materials or anything like that) to regulate the opacity
- go to grease pencil -> apply stroke (seemingly it snaps automaticly to the active camera angle

so know you can draw with the grease pencil and copy the pose of 3D characters :)

Thanks for Susu and Marco

Comment: go to grease pencil -> apply stroke: seemingly it doesn't snap automaticly to the active camera angle. When I do it know my grease pencil strokes appears somewhere else but not in the camera view.